# Is it possible to send and store a Type reference in VB6/VBA?

Tags: vba

I'm working on a VB6 application and I would like to send a Type as a reference and store it in another form. Is this possible?

Sending it is no problem, I just use the `ByRef` keyword:

```
public Sub SetStopToEdit(ByRef currentStop As StopType)
```

But when I try to use Set to store `currentStop` in the receiving module I get the "Object required" error when running the program:

```
Private stopToEdit As StopTypeModule.StopType
' ... Lots of code
Set stopToEdit = currentStop
```

`StopType` is defined as follows in a Module (**not a class module**):

```
Public Type StopType
    MachineName As String
    StartDate As Date
    StartTime As String
    Duration As Double
End Type
```

Is it possible to store the sent reference or do I have to turn `StopType` into a class?

While just setting a local variable works:

```
stopToEdit = currentStop
```

When `stopToEdit` is later changed the change is not visible in the variable sent to `SetStopToEdit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refactor it into a class.

Answer (score 1):

What is StopType? How is it defined? Is a Type the VB6-Record stuff? If so (and if possible), you should redefine it as a class - and only use those, as you will run into problems with Collections otherwise.

Try dropping the `Set` Keyword - Strings, Integers and Numbers, but if I remember correctly, also Records, are not *Set*, they are *Let*, but that is implicit in the assignement:

```
stopToEdit = currentStop
```

**EDIT**: If you want to change the passed in (ByRef) record, do a manual element for element copy instead of reassigning the whole thing - that should do the trick.

At the same time: **DON'T**! ByRef (sadly in VB the default) is not so very cool (to paraphrase my son). Try to design your functions so they don't change arguments passed in - this is what you have a return value for...

Comment: I've changed the original question with some answers to your questions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here is that a StopType is not a reference like an object, but behaves more like an in built type such as LONG. When you do:

stopToEdit = currentStop

You are only taking a copy of currentStop. If you subsequently change stopToEdit, you'll need to copy it back:

currentStop = stopToEdit

That way the value will be passed back out of the Sub.